# How to disable page scroll in html/css/js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I am using **html/css/js** to make a website but a **scroll is appering** *because of some effects* I added. But I don't want a user to see the **scrollbar** or even scroll with **middle mouse button**. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Share your code that is having the issue. Then only some helpful solution can be provided. Without code, only guesswork solutions only can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Guesswork solution***:

```
body {   overflow: hidden;  }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 0):

you can use in CSS

```
overflow:hidden
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

or if you want to have scrolling but you can hide it

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_hide_scrollbar_keep_func

Answer (score 0):

you can use css for this problem if you don't want the scroll to appear

```
overflow: hidden;
```

for more you can refer this
[overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp)